# Write looping HTML in code behind, C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to generate this HTML with the code-behind in C#:

```
<div class="carousel-inner" runat="server" id="divCategory">
   <div class="item active">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <img src="1-1.png" /><br />
            item 1
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
             <img src="1-2.png" /><br />
            item 2
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
             <img src="1-3.png" /><br />
            item 3
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
             <img src="1-4.png" /><br />
            item 4
         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-12">
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <img src="1-5.png" /><br />
            item 5
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <img src="1-6.png" /><br />
            item 6
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <img src="1-7.png" /><br />
            item 7
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <img src="1-8.png" /><br />
            item 8
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="item">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
           <div class="col-sm-3">
              <img src="2-1.png" /><br />
            item 9
           </div>

           <div class="col-sm-3">
              <img src="2-2.png" /><br />
            item 10
           </div>
           <div class="col-sm-3">
              <img src="2-3.png" /><br />
            item 11
           </div>
           <div class="col-sm-3">
              <img src="2-4.png" /><br />
            item 12
           </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <img src="2-5.png" /><br />
            item 13
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
           <img src="2-6.png" /><br />
            item 14
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <img src="2-7.png" /><br />
            item 15
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <img src="2-8.png" /><br />
            item 16
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is what I have so far:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   HtmlGenericControl divItem = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
   divItem.Attributes["class"] = "item active";

   HtmlGenericControl divItem2 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
   divItem2.Attributes["class"] = "item";

   HtmlGenericControl divColumnH = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
   divColumnH.Attributes["class"] = "col-lg-12";

   MySqlDataReader dr = runQuery("SELECT * FROM category");

   while (dr.Read())
   {
      HtmlGenericControl divColumnD1 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
      divColumnD1.Attributes["class"] = "col-sm-3";

      Image img = new Image();
      img.ImageUrl = dr["logoURL"].ToString();

      Label lbl1 = new Label();
      lbl1.Text = "<br>" + dr["name"].ToString();

      divCategory.Controls.Add(divItem);
      divItem.Controls.Add(divColumnH);
      divColumnD1.Controls.Add(img);
      divColumnD1.Controls.Add(lbl1);   
   }
   ConnectionClose();
}
```

- The image URL and image label are obtained from a database.
- Each `div` with class `item` contains ***only*** two `div`s with class `col-lg-12`.
- Each `div` with class `col-lg-12` contains ***only*** four `div`s with class `col-sm-3`.

The problem is, I don't know how to create a third `div` with `col-lg-12` under the `item` `div`.

Comment: I'm half guessing that "contains of 2 div ONLY with class col-lg-12" means "contains ONLY 2 divs with class col-lg-12"

Comment: I think generating HTML in your code behind like this is a bad idea. Do you HAVE to do it this way, or could you use other alternatives? I would suggest a WebUserControl, with a Repeater for the divs.

Comment: Have a look at the TagBuilder class in the System.Web.Mvc namespace.

Comment: @HanletEscaño no, it's NOT necessary to use code-behind. thanks for the suggestion, im new to repeater and webusercontrol, studying now :)

Comment: As I understand you want to list your items in 4 columns structure. You can use asp.net data controls to set column number. Or you can use an html template in a repeater.